# htaccess - Rewrite to capture friendly URL or querystring

Tags: mod-rewrite

I'm trying to come up with one or more rewrite rules that will take either a friendly url or a url containing the full query string.
The plan is to create a text-only page by reading in the URL using PHP's loadHTML.

For example:

Input

```
1. http://www.example.com/disclaimer (http://www.example.com/text/disclaimer on text-only version)
2. http://www.example.com/info/aboutus (http://www.example.com/text/info/aboutus on text-only version)
3. http://www.example.com/news?id=123 (http://www.example.com/text/news?id=123 on text-only version)
```

Output

```
1. http://www.example.com/includes/textonly.php?page=disclaimer
2. http://www.example.com/includes/textonly.php?page=info/aboutus
3. http://www.example.com/includes/textonly.php?news?id=123
```

So on the textonly.php I would use $_GET['page']); for example 1) and 2), and use $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']; for example 3).

For example 1) and 2), I came up with:

```
RewriteRule ^text/(.*) includes/textonly.php?page=$1
```

And for example 3), I came up with:

```
RewriteRule ^text/(.[?]) /includes/textonly.php [QSA]
```

They work independantly but not together.  Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With guidance from Tom and Michael, this is what I've come up with:

in Htaccess send everything to PHP in the querystring:

```
RewriteRule ^text/(.*) /includes/textonly.php [QSA,L]
```

Then in PHP:

```
$page = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'].'/'.str_replace('/text/','',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Seems to work for both friendly urls (2 levels deep tested so far) and querystrings.
Hopefully its okay, so I'll go with this as a solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest handing control over to PHP - I wrote an article on this a while ago - http://tomsbigbox.com/elegant-url-rewriting/ - it details how to send the query string to a PHP file that then decides what to do - so if the page exists for example it will load it, otherwise do something else.

I've found that to be the best solution to URL rewriting.

Comment: Thanks Tom.  I wish I'd have seen your article when I started my website! I've got quite a few things in my htaccess file so would I need to re-do everthing in PHP, or could I just use your solution for the text-only issue I'm working on?

Comment: It depends what you have in your htaccess file really, if you manipulate your query strings in different ways for different pages, you would need to wrap those rules in <FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif|swf|css|js)$"></FilesMatch> for example.

Answer (score 0):

I'd change your rewrite rule to look like this:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/\.]+)/?([^/\.]+)?/?$ /includes/textonly.php?page=$1&id=$2 [L,NC]
```

Then slightly modify your Input URLs to look like this:

```
1. http://www.example.com/disclaimer
2. http://www.example.com/info/aboutus
3. http://www.example.com/news/123
```

And they would point to these URLs:

```
1. http://www.example.com/includes/textonly.php?page=disclaimer&id=
2. http://www.example.com/includes/textonly.php?page=info&id=aboutus
3. http://www.example.com/includes/textonly.php?page=news&id=123
```

The regex above will match anything between the `/`, not including a `/` or a `.`. The second half is optional, so in that rule, you could only go two directories deep.

Controlling all three URLs in the same way will make your logic a little cleaner on the `textonly.php` page as you do not need to write special logic for the first two URLs compared to the last.

Comment: Thanks Michael.  I'm not sure I'll be able to modify the input urls as some are more than 2 levels deep with many parameters.  Ideally I need to find something that will handle friendly urls and query strings... if this is possible?

Comment: In your case, I would use `$_SERVER['QUERY_STRING']` for all of your URLs and rely on PHP to do the processing then. @Tom Walter's answer may be your best option.